# Regex: Filter out text before last occurrence

Tags: regex

```
TEXT: R:\Everybody\OlegB\DiskCleaner\1\NewsFeed\Regional\Bray People_2010-04-14_v3.zip

REGEX: (?<titleid>.*)_(?<issuedate>(19|20)[0-9]{2}[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))_v(?<layoutver>[0-9]*)
```

I need apply REGEX to the following part of TEXT:

Bray People_2010-04-14_v3.zip

How can I filter out all text before last occurrence of slash and apply expression to the reminded part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to prepend `^.*\` to your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(?<titleid>[^\\_]*)_(?<issuedate>(19|20)[0-9]{2}[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))_v(?<layoutver>[0-9]*)
```

This will avoid matching backslashes and underscores for the `<titleid>`.