# Trim all text before last Regex match

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to remove all text before the last occurrence of a Regex match without also removing the match or having to replace it with any other text. Here is a few lines sample lines from the file I am parsing:

N3.C2.R1: 19 00000000 00000000 00**0000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
N0.C0.R0N3.C3.R1: 19 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
.N3.C3.R0: 18 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000*00 00000000 00000000
Writing to rank 1...N3.C1.R3: -22 0000000* 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000*00 00000000 00000000

The first line is the ideal line and matches what the return should be. My Regex pattern is as follows:

```
string pattern = @"N\d\.C\d\.R\d:";
```

The pattern returns all the above strings, but I need to trim all of the text that occurs before the last occurrence of the pattern in order to return a line that looks like the first one. I've looked at a number of questions here that are similar, but I haven't been able to find an answer that actually works in my code, or that makes sense to me.

Keep in mind, the above examples are not an exhaustive list of possibilities. This is why I'm trying to use Regex instead of string methods.

For reference, here are the similar questions I read through before asking this one:

[Regex + Remove all text before match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841129/regex-remove-all-text-before-match)
[RegEx Multple Matches in Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390847/regex-multple-matches-in-text?rq=1)
[Regex: Filter out text before last occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821023/regex-filter-out-text-before-last-occurrence)

EDIT: I should point out, the lines I am working with are a very small subset of the information included in the original file. All of the sample lines I posted are examples of "good" information (i.e. information I can use), but the first line is what the final output should look like.

Comment: trim what!......show us your expected output for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
string str = Regex.Replace(input, @"(.+?)(N\d\.C\d\.R\d:)", "$2");
```

Comment: This solution will work but I'm a bit confused as to why you (spugm1r3) would ever want to do this. Isn't it better to simply return the last match as your result without manipulating the original string?

Comment: @Ameen agree, it's more efficient just to return the last match

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Vlad L, your answer is perfect. @Ameen, honestly, I was just stuck inside of my own problem. I've never used Regex before this project and once I stumbled across a pattern that "mostly" worked, I just started working from inside those results. That said, a lot of the syntax in Vlad's response is simply stuff I haven't stumbled across or made sense of yet. On that note: Vlad, can you explain the $2? It obviously works, I just want to know the mechanics of it so this doesn't turn into a "one-of" answer for me.

Comment: @spugm1r3 welcome. brackets representing matching groups. $1 contains everything that were matched inside of (.+?), $2 contains (N\d\.C\d\.R\d:) etc. so Regex.Replace will replace in my example $1+$2 with $2. I can't explain it very good in English, but the keyword for your question is matching group. hope that helps

Comment: @VladL that makes perfect sense. It's also exactly where I was getting stuck before... I could find the last match, but I really didn't know how to replace the preceding text with the match (instead of a predetermined string).

Answer (score 0):

This approach also returns what might possibly follow your last match (e.g. the remainder of the line after the number):

```
string pattern = @"^N\d\.C\d\.R\d:";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (matches.Count > 0) {
    string result = input.Substring(matches[matches.Count - 1].Index);
}
```

I also included `^` in order to search for the beginning of the line explicitly. This requires the `Multiline` regex option.